# nginx www domain does not work when redirecting

Tags: nginx, web, dns

I am having issues redirecting content with http://www.example.com. In other words, http://example works fine and redirects to https, but http://www.example.com does not.

Below is my nginx config

```
server {
  listen 80;
  listen [::]:80;
  server_name example.com;
  return 301 https://www.example.com$request_uri;
}

server {
 listen 80;
 listen [::]:80;
 server_name www.example.com;
 return 301 https://www.example.com$request_uri;
}

server {

listen 443 ssl http2;
server_name www.example.com;

sendfile on;

ssl_certificate /usr/share/example_chain.crt;
ssl_certificate_key /usr/share/7a45ae3816f4bc8f.pem;
default_type application/octet-stream;

gzip on;
gzip_http_version 1.1;
gzip_disable      "MSIE [1-6]\.";
gzip_min_length   256;
gzip_vary         on;
gzip_proxied      expired no-cache no-store private auth;
gzip_types        text/plain text/css application/json application/javascript application/x- 
javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript;
gzip_comp_level   9;

root /usr/share/nginx/html;

location / {
  try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html =404;
 }

}
```

In addition, I have a docker container that serves request from port 443 on my ec2 instance to port 443 inside the docker container.

Before I had this ->

```
server {
  listen 80;
  listen [::]:80;
  server_name www.example.com example.com;
  return 301 https://www.example.com$request_uri;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use IF module in nginx to fix this issue. Refer the below config.

```
server {
         listen 80;
         server_name example.com www.example.com;
         return 301 https://www.example.com$request_uri;
}

server {
        listen 443;
        server_name example.com;
        root /var/www/html;
        index index.html index.php;

        location / {
           try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
        }


        ssl on;
        ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/cert.crt;
        ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/key.key;
        ssl_session_timeout 5m;

        if ($scheme = http) {
                 rewrite ^/(.*)$ https://www.example.com/$1 permanent;
         }

         if ($host !~* ^www\.) {
                 rewrite ^/(.*)$ https://www.example.com/$1 permanent;
         }


}
```

Comment: i'm still getting the issue :( thank you so much for the help ! i'm typing (http) www.example.com and i want that to go to (https) www.example.com

Comment: can you curl -I example.co and post here the http response you are getting.

Comment: this is using the above configuration !   -> HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
Server: nginx/1.12.2
Date: Wed, 08 Apr 2020 08:04:58 GMT
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Connection: close
Location: (https)://www.example.com

Comment: actually I include this  ->  if ($host ~* ^www.example.com$) {
       return 301 (https)://www.example.com$request_uri;
    } in my server { listen 80 }

Comment: @AurelianoYepez if you use $host ~* ^www.example.com$ Nginx will redirect the requests that only come with www.  Instead, use this if ($host !~* ^www\.) this will be fix.